# How to use wtforms.po with Flask-WTF

Tags: flask-wtforms

```
from wtforms.fields.simple import TextField, PasswordField
from wtforms import validators
from wtforms.ext.i18n.form import Form


class  BaseForm(Form):
     LANGUAGES = ['zh']
class LoginForm(BaseForm):
    username = TextField("Username", [validators.Required()])
    psw = PasswordField("Password", [validators.Required()])
```

The above code works fine, the form prompt message can be translated to Chinese.

What problem I have is how to use Flask-wtf instead of wtforms?
I tried:

```
from wtforms import validators
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields.simple import TextField, PasswordField
class  BaseForm(Form):
     LANGUAGES = ['zh']
class LoginForm(BaseForm):
    username = TextField("Username", [validators.Required()])
    psw = PasswordField("Password", [validators.Required()])
```

The prompt message is still English. Could someone give me advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/

add the following code to your app script

```
  from flask.ext.babel import Babel
  babel = Babel(app)
  app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'zh_Hans_CN'
```

create babel.cfg next to your application:

```
  [python: **.py]
  [jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
  extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

copy wtforms.po / wtforms.mo to folder "translations/zh_Hans_CN/LC_MESSAGES" (created by Flask-Babel) which next to your application

Then no need touch anything with Flask-WTF, it will works fine with Flask-Babel auto.